# BsonSerializationException when passing concrete Parameter in constructor to fill more general Property with .net driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a `Identity` class that is extended by two classes `StringIdentity` and `GuidIdentity`. I want to use them in Objects as Property and save them in a MongoDb. For Example a class would look like this:

```
public class MyEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        public MyEvent(GuidIdentity entityId)
        {
            EntityId = entityId;
        }

        public Identity EntityId { get; }
    }
```

IDomainEvent forces me to implement the `Identity` Property, so I can (and do not want to) change the property type to `GuidIdentity`.

When I deserialize my class I get an exception like this:

> Creator map for class Microwave.Eventstores.UnitTests. MyEvent has 1
>   arguments, but none are configured.

Which seems logical according to the .net driver doku, as my property does not match the type of the parameter and therefore can not be serialized. I had the solution to use the `Identity` as constructor parameter or make the constructor private and instantiate the class with a static `Create` method that takes the `GuidIdentity` as parameter. I also messed around with the BsonClassMap, but I really do not want to write all this kind of duplicate code for every class that implements `IDomainEvent`

So is there a way to tell the .net Driver to use the concrete class from the constructor instead of the more general PropertyType for all Types? Some kind of silver bullet solution? ;)

I am very new to mongodb so I am not aware of all the tricks that come with it, maybe someone can help me out here.

Comment: Just for clarification: are you saying that you are able to serialize/deserialize `MyEvent` to Mongo now?

Comment: And, when it reads/writes from Mongo, you want it to save/retrieve `EntityID` as a `GuidIdentity`, as it is in reality, rather than the more generic `Identity`? That's what you're asking how to do?

Comment: @AnnL. 
I want to retrieve it as a GuidIdentiy, but the field should stay as the more generic Identity type. And yes, I can serialize it when I make the constructor private and create the classes with a static create class or just use the more general Type Identity in the constructor. But I want my constructor to be specific, so I can not instantiate a class that acutally wants a GuidIdentity with a StringIdentity.